# Loading com Ajax

Tags: ajax

Queria saber como fazer uma imagem, ou alguma coisa, para indicar que a página está dando loading. Tenho um processo que demora uns 7 segundos e para o usuário não ficar clicando achando que não foi, gostaria de exibir uma imagem de loading ou algo do tipo. Segue parte do meu código

```
<a onclick="Open('/CMS/Pedido/Index');" href="javascript:void(null);">Ver Pedidos</a>
```

Tentei adicionar uma imagem na div mas não deu muito certo:

```
 <script>
    function Open(url) {
        var img = $("<img />").attr('src', '~/Content/Images/loading.gif'); 
        $("#Conteudo").clear().append(img);

        $("#Conteudo").load(url);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12181/sistema-de-progresso-de-carregamento-de-site/12187#12187 , já. Tem solução para esse pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) do jQuery é limitado. Vamos substituir o seu `$('#Conteudo').load(url)` por isso [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('body').append('<div class="loader">Carregando. Aguarde, por favor.</div>');
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $('#Conteudo').html(response);
        $('.loader').remove();
    }
});
```

O [`beforeSend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) do `$.ajax` irá executar algo que você queira assim que você enviar a requisição – neste caso, do tipo `GET` para `url`. O [`success`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) é o engatilhador caso a sua requisição chegue no seu destino, também no caso, `url`.

Portanto, quando disparamos a requisição, carregamos o loader. Quando ela é respondida com sucesso – provavelmente depois dos 7 segundos que estão ocorrendo – nós apagamos o loader da tela.

Basicamente é isso. Implementações ficam por sua conta.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia iniciar o *loading* no momento em que a função `Open()` fosse disparada, e fechá-lo assim que a resposta do AJAX retornasse. Exemplo:

```
function Open(url){
    //Chama o loader
    loaderInit();

    //Faz a requisição AJAX
    $.get(url,function(response){
        // Assim que algo retornar, fecha o loader
        loaderClose();
        // E popula o elemento #conteudo com o que foi retornado
        $('#conteudo').html(response);
    });
}

function loaderInit(){
    // Se não tiver nenhum loader no DOM
    if($('#loader').length < 1){
        // Cria o loader
        $('body').append('<div id="loader"></div>');
    }
}

function loaderClose(){
    // Remove o loader do DOM
    $('#loader').remove();
}
```